# Make anchor tag with image clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I am using one plugin that one is http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-2. But i want to implement clickable image.

In this plugin show image by anchor tag like this:

```
<div style="padding:120px 0;">
        <div id="thumbnail-slider">
            <div class="inner">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/6.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/7.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

I want to redirect page after click on this image. Give me some idea about this. It is possible to Make anchor tag with image clickable with this plugin?
Give me some idea. 
Thanks

Comment: `<a class="thumb" href="//img/7.jpg"><img src='img/7.jpg'></a>` should show an image and on click it should take you to it.

Comment: Put an image tag inside your anchor tag and use the href of the anchor to direct to the page with the src of the image set to the image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to listen to the `click` event, then do whatever you want.

In the below demo, if you click on the front slide it will redirect to google. If not, it will do nothing. If you want to redirect when `click` on any image, just remove the `if` statement that check that the image in the front:

**Note:** It will not do the redirect because of security reason so you can see it in this [bin](http://jsbin.com/vikejo/edit?html,js,output).

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.thumb'), function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Check if the image in the front
    if (this.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
      location.href = this.dataset.href;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/2/thumbnail-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/2/thumbnail-slider.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnail-slider">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/6.jpg" data-href="http://google.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/7.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/2.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/3.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/4.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/5.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/8.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/9.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/10.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/11.jpg" data-href="http://facebook.com"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/vikejo/2/edit?html,js,output

**Edit**
To redirect to a different URL for each image, you can add a `data-` attribute, in this case `data-href`, then, when user clicks on the image he redirect to the URL which is the value of the attribute.

**The link**

```
<a class="thumb" href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumb/img/6.jpg" data-href="http://google.com"></a>
```

**In the click event**

```
location.href = this.dataset.href;
```

Comment: This answer correct. But can we redirect functionality in HTML code. Because i want to insert separate links to all images.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<a class="thumb" href="img/6.jpg"></a>
```

you can use

```
<a class="thumb" href="img/6.jpg"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

In anchor tag, you can also change the href attribute if you want to redirect it to any url, like this:

```
 <a class="thumb" href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<li><a href="/"><img class="thumb" src="1.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a></li>
```

source :- http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="padding:120px 0;">
    <div id="thumbnail-slider">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="thumb" href="#target_url"><img src="img/6.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="thumb" href="#target_url"><img src="img/7.jpg"></a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Use image tag inside a tag to display image as hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="thumb" href="#target_url"><img src="img/6.jpg"></a>
```

This is simple and straight forward answer